# How I can stop the DNS server to transfer directly to my website when access phpmyadmin

Tags: centos, mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I have 4 web servers on the same domain and when I access `51.32.xx.xx/phpmyadmin` It is directly changed to `mydomain.com/phpmyadmin`  how I can stop it to change because I cannot access To another MySQL server

Comment: (1) Do not answer to your question when you add information to the original question: just edit the question. (2) By the looks of it, your example.com.conf sets up an infinite redirect loop to itself (http redirects to https, https redirects - again - to https) (3) It appears you ae going at this by trial and error, which is error prone, time consuming and low pay-off. You should read up on apache's configuration.

Comment: Well, I didn't know, actually, the example.com.conf file didn't exist I created it, and as you said the site is in the HTTPS to HTTPS loop and thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem with HTTPS when I enter HTTP it takes me directly to HTTPS. I solved this problem just by typing the link manually, **starting with HTTPS** `https://52.32.xx.xx/phpmyadmin`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming apache is your webserver, with centos-like configuration, the "regular" behavior, for non-hostname qualified urls, is to (try to) serve it according to the "main" webserver definition, then according to whatever virtualhost is found first in configuration. If that does not suit you, you'll have to change the alias for phpmyadmin in one/all of your vitualhosts and invoke the proper hostnam-qualified url OR change the alias for the main webserver (usually defined in /etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf)

Comment: Thanks for the answer,  I have modified the virtual host